# How to renew kubernetes ssl certs

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, openssl, certificate, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm using kubeadm to build k8s cluster and default ssl certs will be used in 1 year.
I plan use cfssl or opensll to gen new certs with 10 years use.
Could anynone pls help me.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can generate certs using cfssl or openssl and store in a directory and specify that directory in Kubeadm init and kubeadm will not generate certs and use the provided certs.

```
kubeadm init --cert-dir
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#custom-certificates

Kubeadm also provides cert renew mechanism for renewing certs for 1 year.

```
kubeadm alpha certs renew
```

Since you have a running cluster which signs certs with 1 year of validity you can change this flag of kube controller manager default duration of cert signed to sign certs for 10 years.

```
--experimental-cluster-signing-duration duration     Default: 8760h0m0s
```

Once this is done you can use below guide to sign cert valid for 10 years.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#renew-certificates-with-the-kubernetes-certificates-api

Comment: Could you pls help with a tutorial? And how can I change it when my cluster is running.

Comment: This command renew 1 year, I want to extend to 10 years or more.

Answer (score 1):

To renew Kubernetes certs for 10 years (not recommended).
[image]

- Check certs expiration

  `kubeadm alpha certs check-expiration --config="/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml"`
- Back up the existing Kubernetes certificates

  `mkdir -p $HOME/fcik8s-old-certs/pki`

  `/bin/cp -p /etc/kubernetes/pki/*.* $HOME/fcik8s-old-certs/pki`
- Back up the existing configurtion files

  `/bin/cp -p /etc/kubernetes/*.conf $HOME/fcik8s-old-certs`
- Back up your home configuration

  `mkdir -p $HOME/fcik8s-old-certs/.kube`

  `/bin/cp -p ~/.kube/config $HOME/fcik8s-old-certs/.kube/.`
- Add *--cluster-signing-duration* flag (*--experimental-cluster-signing-duration* prior to 1.19) for *kube-controller-manager*

  > Edit /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml

  ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     labels:
       component: kube-controller-manager
       tier: control-plane
     name: kube-controller-manager
     namespace: kube-system
   spec:
     containers:
     - command:
       - kube-controller-manager
       ...
       - --experimental-cluster-signing-duration=87600h
       ...
   ...
  ```

  87600h ~ 10 years
- Renew all certs

  `kubeadm alpha certs renew all --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml --use-api`
- Approve the cert request

  `kubectl get csr`

  `kubectl certificate approve <cert_request>`
- Update the kubeconfig file

  `kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml`
- Overwrite the original admin file with the newly generated admin configuration file

  `cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config`

  `chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`
- Restart components

  `docker restart $(docker ps | grep etcd  | awk '{ print $1 }')`

  `docker restart $(docker ps | grep kube-apiserver  | awk '{ print $1 }')`

  `docker restart $(docker ps | grep kube-scheduler  | awk '{ print $1 })`

  `docker restart $(docker ps | grep kube-controller  | awk '{ print $1 }')`

  `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet`
- Check api-server cert expiration

  `echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 127.0.0.1:6443 -servername api 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate`